# How do I parallel process in a for loop. My code parallels the operation improperly

Tags: c++, openmp, gmp

Beginner with OpenMp. I am running on an AMD 3970X.
I have a problem with a loop, more than one thread working on the same iteration.
The code should work on a mpq_t sum of 1/n, n=1..100.
The output is n, threadid, num, den, repeating, non-repeating, and, time.
Sorry if this is long.
I have played with placement of the 2 pragma statements, no success.

I changed the code as suggested, and now get a compile error:

```
digits.cc:193:54: error: user defined reduction not found for 'sum'
  193 | #pragma omp for schedule(static, chunk), reduction(+:sum)
```

```
// digits.cpp - implementation of digits with libgmp

// 20111123 tomdean - initial conversion from digits.c

// The rational number, sum(1/k,k=1..n) has three components,
// An integer >= 1, s1..ss
// A sequence of non-repeating digits, n1..nn
// A sequence of repeating digits, r1..rr
// The sum is s1..ss . n1..nn r1..rr r1..rr ...

// Calculating the number of integers, non-repeating digits, and,
// repeating digits for n > 83 requires hours#pragma omp for schedule(static, chunk), reduction(sum:+)
 of computer time on a
// 4.2GHz Core i7-3930k.

// The algorithm is simple, all values are integers and thus exact.

// From the rational number, sum, extract the numerator and denominator.
// Calculate q = nu/de, r = q - q*de.
// checked saved_r for r.  If found, return
// if num_saved_r < SAVE_MAX, save r in r_saved[num_saved_r++]
// 

#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <sys/time.h> // time calculations
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit
#include <unistd.h>   // getopt
#include <omp.h>      // openmp
#define NUM_CHK 50
#pragma omp for schedule(static, chunk), reduction(sum:+)

using namespace std;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// usage
void usage(char *me) {
    cout << "Usage: " << me << " [-f <n>] [-t <m>] [-h]" << endl
         << "Where:" << endl
         << "  -f <n> - from <n> default 10" << endl
         << "  -t <n> - to <n>   default n+10" << endl
         << "  -h     - show this message" << endl;
    return;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// calc_time
double calc_time( timeval *start,  timeval *stop) {
    long sec, usec;
    sec  = stop->tv_sec  - start->tv_sec;
    usec = stop->tv_usec - start->tv_usec;
    if (usec < 0) {
        sec--;
        usec += 1000000L;
    }
    return (double)sec + ((double) usec)/1.0E6;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// calc_digits
void calc_digits(int idx, mpq_class sum) {
    long chkidx = 0;
    long m;
    mpz_t tnu, de, nu, q, r;
    mpz_t chk[NUM_CHK]; // saved r
    unsigned long s;
    struct timeval start, stop;
    struct timezone zone;
    int tid;

    tid = omp_get_thread_num();

    mpz_inits(nu, de, q, r, tnu, NULL);
    mpz_set(nu, sum.get_num_mpz_t());
    mpz_set(de, sum.get_den_mpz_t());

    for (s=0; s<NUM_CHK; s++) {
        mpz_init(chk[s]);
    }
    (void)gettimeofday(&start, &zone);
    //cout << nu << " " << de << endl;
    chkidx = 0;
    // q = nu/de;  r = nu - q*de;
    mpz_fdiv_qr(q, r, nu, de);
    s = 1;
    mpz_set(chk[chkidx], r);
    // cout << "init "
    //     << nu << ' '
    //     << de << ' '
    //     << q << ' '
    //     << r << ' '
    //     << chkidx << ' '
    //     << chk[chkidx] <<  endl;
    chkidx++;
    m = -1;
    while (1) {
        mpz_mul_si(tnu, r, 10L);
        //tq = tnu/de;  r = tnu - tq*de;
        mpz_fdiv_r(r,tnu,de);
        {
            long idx;
            m = -1;
            for (idx=0; idx<chkidx; idx++) {
                if (mpz_cmp(r, chk[idx]) == 0) m = idx;
            }
        }
        if (m >= 0) break;
        s++;
        if (chkidx < NUM_CHK) {
            mpz_set(chk[chkidx], r);
            // cout << "loop "/
            //     << tnu << ' '
            //     << de << ' '
            //     << q << ' '
            //     << r << ' '
            //     << chkidx << ' '
            //     << chk[chkidx] <<  endl;
            chkidx++;
        }
    }
    // at this point, m is num non-recurring
    //                s is the number of iterations, the total digit count
    (void)gettimeofday(&stop, &zone);
    cout << idx << ' ' << ' ' << tid << ' ' << nu
         << ' ' << de
        //<< ' ' << nu/de
         << ' ' << m
         << ' ' << s-(unsigned long long)m
         << ' ' << calc_time(&start,&stop) << endl;

    mpz_clears(q, r, tnu, NULL);
    for (s=0; s<NUM_CHK; s++) mpz_clear(chk[s]);

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// main
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    long idx;
    long long from, to;
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    char ch;
    int chunk = 60;

    from = 10;   // pre-calc sum(1/k,k=1..9) start processing at k=10
    to   = 100;  // sum(1/k,k=1..100)
  
    // check optional arguments
    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "hf:t:")) != -1) {
        switch (ch) {
        case 'f':
            if (sscanf(optarg, "%Ld", &from) != 1) {
                usage(argv[0]);
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        case 't':
            if (sscanf(optarg, "%Ld", &to) != 1) {
                usage(argv[0]);
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        case 'h':
        default:
            usage(argv[0]);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    cout << '#' << endl;
    cout << "# Calculate sum(1/k,k=1..n) for n = 1 to 100." << endl;
    cout << '#' << endl;
    cout << "# Columns are: N" << endl;
    cout << "#              Numerator" << endl;
    cout << "#              Denominator" << endl;
    cout << "#              Number of non-recurringdigits" << endl;
    cout << "#              Number of recurring digits." << endl;
    cout << "#              Elapsed time in seconds." << endl;
    cout << '#' << endl;
    cout << "# Started " << ctime(&now); // ctime is /n/0 terminated
    cout << '#' << endl;

    mpq_class sum(1,1);
    mpz_t nu, de;
    mpz_inits(nu, de, NULL);
  
    // advance to n = from
    for (idx=2; idx<from; idx++) {
        sum += mpq_class(1,idx);
    }
    //cout << sum << endl;

    // calculate to n = 100
#pragma omp parallel default(shared)
#pragma omp for schedule(static, chunk) reduction(+:sum)
    for (idx=from; idx<to+1; idx++) {
        //cout << idx << " ";
        sum += mpq_class(1,idx);
        //cout << sum << endl;
        calc_digits(idx, sum);
        //mpz_set(nu, sum.get_num_mpz_t());
        //mpz_set(de, sum.get_den_mpz_t());
        //calc_digits(nu,de);
    }

    mpz_clears(nu, de, NULL);
    // digits.cc -
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At iteration 78, threads 11 and 20 seem to be working on the same data and produce the same output. Iteration 77 seems to be missing. Iteration 82 has a similar problem, with iteration seeming to be missing.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to mark the `for` loop as `#pragma omp for` so that the iterations get distributed over the threads. Or you can combine that with the `omp parallel`.
2. The next problem is your `sum += ....` statement. Since all threads access the `sum` variable, you need to mark your parallel loop as a `reduction(+:sum)`.
3. The `omp schedule` by itself doesn't do anything. Put it on the `omp for` line.

Comment: 4. Note that your output may be mixed because of `cout << xxx << yyy << zzz;`. I suggest  composing your string before you pass it to `cout`.

Comment: I changed the code:
```
    // calculate to n = 100
#pragma omp parallel default(shared) shared(idx, sum)
#pragma omp for schedule(static, chunk), reduction(sum:+)
    for (idx=from; idx<to+1; idx++) {
```
and now get an error,
digits.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
digits.cc:193:56: error: expected unqualified-id before '+' token
  193 | #pragma omp for schedule(static, chunk), reduction(sum:+)

Comment: @tomdean1939 Please add an update to your original post, the code cannot be read here.

Comment: @Laci Good point. Use `stringstream ss; ss << stuff ; ss << morestuff; cout << ss.str();`

Comment: @tomdean1939 Sorry: should be `reduction(+:sum)`. Do you have a book or tutorial where you can look up this sort of stuff?

Comment: @Victor I saw that and changed it to reduction(+:sum).  Now, I get a different error, same statement.  Looking at the ref manual and examples, I do not see a solution.
I changed my original postl

Comment: You do not need the second `#pragma omp for schedule(static, chunk) reduction(+:sum)` line. Note also that no comma needed between `schedule` and `reduction`.

Comment: Looks like reduction does not  like mpq_t either.  I get the same error when I change to mpq_t.